# How can I design these two tables to prevent corrupt data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a `comments` table, a comment either references an answer or a question as a foreign key :

```
id primary key not null,
question_id  references questions(id),
answer_id references answers(id),
```

either `answer_id` or `question_id` will be populated and the other will be null.

Now the other table is `notifications`, whenever a comment is created, I create a notification:

```
id primary key not null,
comment_id references comments(id),
question_id references questions(id),
answer_id references answers(id),
```

Either `question_id` or `answer_id` will be populated, but I want to make sure it's consistent with what's populated for that `comment` record.

How do I make sure that a notification will reference the same resource referenced by the comment itself? In other words, if I have a comment that references a question, and then I want to create a notification for that comment but make it reference an answer, the database shouldn't allow that. How do I impose such a constraint?

Comment: I think you might be able to solve the problem using inheritance and having three different types of notification tables.

Comment: Your current design does not appear to be normalized.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you suggest a way to normalize the comments table?

Comment: If you do want to keep `question_id` and `answer_id` in the `notifications` table, then create one foreign key that consists of three columns `(comment_id, question_id, answer_id)` and references only `comments` table. Postgres [supports it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are misusing "normalized". It means a table cannot usefully be replaced by projections that join to it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov What you propose doesn't work. The needed constraint would involve NULL in the referenced column when there is NULL in the referencing column, and FK referenced columns must be NOT NULL.

Comment: Your 'two/multiple FKs/links/associations/references to one table' design is an anti-pattern for your situation, which involves 'sql/database subtyping/inheritance'. Google these.

Comment: @philipxy yes I figured that out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normalize the tables and use the reference from notifications to comments to find question_id and answer_id.

```
create table comments (
  id serial primary key,
  question_id int references questions(id),
  answer_id int references answers(id)
);

create table notifications (
  id primary key not null,
  comment_id int references comments(id)
);
```

Access the date using a join:

```
select question.*
from notifications
join comments on comments_id = comments.id
join questions on question_id = questions.id;
```

Comment: Interesting, do you think it's also a good idea to add a new filed `type` to notifications to tell whether this comment references a question or an answer?

Comment: NVM my comment, great answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Id' say no, that would be another data point that could be inconsistent (a row marked as `question` but only linking to an answer).

If it's helpful for you, you could define a view containing a calculated type field.

Comment: Thank you, I think I learned from this answer what I didn't learn from reading multiple blogs.

Comment: And I misread your comment, a `type` in notifications would be a bad idea, a not so bad idea (but still not good) would be adding it to comments.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making this over complicated.
you should have a table that has the comments in it as well as having the type.  No nulls needed and is normalized

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 comment VARCHAR,
 is_answer BOOLEAN
);
```